# Renaming the cell based on it's value

Tags: excel

Suppose I have a column in excel as Age  
Age 
43
54
62
71
I want to rename it as

Age
41-50
51-60
61-70
71-80

How do i do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason behind doing this, besides just wanting to rename?

Comment: I am doing a project in R and I want the variables to be nominal and not continuous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data like:

[image]

Running this macro:

```
Sub luxation()
    Dim i As Long, r As Range, v As Variant

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For i = 2 To 5
            Set r = Cells(i, "A")
            v = r.Value
            r.Value = .Round(v, -1) & "-" & .RoundUp(v, -1)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

You can change the limits in the loop to cover all your data.

Comment: I have changed the range a bit...my bad...
Can you please give a code for this ... 
Sorry for the edits

Comment: I have made the following edits and it is working fine ....


Sub luxation()
    Dim i As Long, r As Range, v As Variant

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For i = 2 To 1507
            Set r = Cells(i, "C")
            v = r.Value
            r.Value = .RoundDown(v, -1) & "-" & .RoundDown(v, -1) + 10
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

When working with changing ranges I suggest something like this:

```
Sub test()
  Dim a As Variant, b As Long
  For Each a In Selection.Cells
    If IsNumeric(a.Value) And Len(a.Value) Then
      b = Int(a.Value / 10) * 10
      a.Value = b + 1 & 0 - b - 10
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

This also works if you select the whole column C. But it will change ALL numbers in the selected range in the format you requested (empty cells stay empty but 0 will become "1-10")

However: doing this for bigger ranges may freeze excel for a bit (just the calculation-time). In that case you may want to use a faster code like that:

```
Sub test2()
  Dim b As Long, i As Long, j As Long, vars As Variant
  vars = Intersect(Selection, Selection.Parent.UsedRange).Value
  For i = 1 To UBound(vars)
    For j = 1 To UBound(vars, 2)
      If IsNumeric(vars(i, j)) And Len(vars(i, j)) Then
        b = Int(vars(i, j) / 10) * 10
        vars(i, j) = b + 1 & 0 - b - 10
      End If
    Next
  Next
  Intersect(Selection, Selection.Parent.UsedRange).Value = vars
End Sub
```

And if you have a set range where the numbers always are (and don't want to select) you also can preselect it with a code like that:

```
Sub test3()
  Dim b As Long, i As Long, j As Long, vars As Variant, rng As Range
  Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C20000")
  vars = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange).Value
  For i = 1 To UBound(vars)
    For j = 1 To UBound(vars, 2)
      If IsNumeric(vars(i, j)) And Len(vars(i, j)) Then
        b = Int(vars(i, j) / 10) * 10
        vars(i, j) = b + 1 & 0 - b - 10
      End If
    Next
  Next
  Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange).Value = vars
End Sub
```

If you still have any question, just write a comment ;)